# Multiplying transformation matrix to a vector

Tags: python, opengl

I have done a series of transformations using glMultMatrix.  How do I multiply a vector (nX, nY, nZ, 1) to the matrix I have from the transformation?  How do I get that matrix to multiply with a vector?

```
pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: invalid operation
```

I am getting above error if I use glMultMatrix. I need to call this multiplication between glBegin and glEnd.

Comment: Lets say you have two matrix A (m x n) and B (p x q), the matrix product [C] = [A] x [B] will be p x q order; and the operation is only valid if the number of columns in A is equal to the number of rows in B, it is: n = p.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, you want something that returns the result of a Matrix-vector product between the current ModelView/Projection matrix and a vector you specify.

In that case, OpenGL can't do the multiplication for you. Instead, you need to extract the current matrix and do the multiplication yourself:

```
import numpy as np
someVector = np.array([2,3,4,5])
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glMultMatrix(...)
modelViewMatrix = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
result = np.dot(modelViewMatrix, someVector)
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might need to get both the ModelView and Projection matrices and multiply them first.